# Linux: md Software RAID array out of sync

Tags: linux, centos, software-raid

We had a CentOS server report this software RAID issue via /etc/cron.weekly/99-raid-check

> WARNING: mismatch_cnt is not 0 on /dev/md2

Answer (score 2):

One of our system admins found a note online that said to check `/sys/block/md2/md/mismatch_cnt` and it showed 400 blocks out of sync between the two drives.

Solution: `echo repair >/sys/block/md2/md/sync_action`

Hope it helps someone else.